# C executing a pipe: execlp works while execvp doesn't

Tags: c, exec, fork, pipe, gnu

Could someone explain to me why this gives the normal behavior (ls | cat)

```
int fd[2]; pipe(fd);
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid > 0) {
    close(fd[0]);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    execlp("ls","ls",NULL);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    close(fd[1]);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    execlp("cat","cat",NULL);
} else {
    error(1, errno, "forking error");
}
```

but when I change execlp to execvp suddenly nothing is output and exit status is 255? Code:

```
int fd[2]; pipe(fd);
pid_t pid = fork();
if(pid > 0) {
    close(fd[0]);
    close(STDOUT_FILENO);
    dup2(fd[1],STDOUT_FILENO);
    char **args = {"ls", NULL};
    execvp("ls",args);
} else if (pid == 0) {
    close(fd[1]);
    close(STDIN_FILENO);
    dup2(fd[0],STDIN_FILENO);
    char **args = {"cat", NULL};
    execvp("cat",args);
} else {
    error(1, errno, "forking error");
}
```

I'd really like to use execvp because I'll be executing commands with variable length arg lists. Help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Did you enable all your compiler warnings?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`char **args = {"ls", NULL};` should be `char *args[] = {"ls", NULL};`, and the same for the second `args` (for `cat`).

(It's too late here, so I can't think of the reason for the first one to *compile*. At least it gives a warning).

Comment: Oh hahah you're completely right. I forgot how important warnings are. Thank you.